# Install kernel 2.6.x headers on a 3.11 machine and build driver using 2.6

Tags: kernel, compiling, c

I have a proprietary SDK for an embedded device which was built with Linux kernel 2.6.32 and is dependent upon its headers.

With newer kernel (3.11.x), it fails to build complaining about missing several data structures.

I am trying to install 2.6.x headers only (and source if required) on a 3.11 kernel machine. Is that possible? Any advice into how do i go about doing that?

*Update:*

My code goes inside attempts to make from following:

```
 -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build SUBDIRS=`pwd`  modules; 
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
```

I need to tell it to use 2.6.x instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just download and extract the 2.6.x kernel source code into a working directory in your home directory.

You can either use the ubuntu code or download a kernel from kernel.org, depending on your needs and if you need the ubuntu patches (apparmor and other patches) or not.

The linux kernel source code contains the headers.

Comment: Thank you. So i would install it the regular way? How would i tell some other Make files to use headers from this kernel instead?

Comment: I can not tell from what you posted. Normally one would apply a patch. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Updated the question a bit. It currently goes in /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build SUBDIRS=pwd where i intend to install 2.6 and want it to use that instead

Comment: Errors are about read_proc_t, write_proc_t etc. data structures which have been removed from kernel since 3.x

Comment: You may need to install a 2.6 kernel if you are dependent on the compiled modules in /lib/modules . You can try extracting the source code to `/usr/src/2.6.x`